# Find an element on the page based on a variable using CasperJS' getElementByXPath

Tags: javascript, xpath, casperjs

I have an issue using `__utils__.getElementByXPath()` with variable xpath parameter, see example:

The licid is given as argv (`--licid=FAT32`) at cli execution of the script and is correctly acknowledged from CasperJS.

```js
casper.then(function() {
    var xpath_lic = '//*[contains(text(), "' + casper.cli.get("licid") + '")]';
    this.echo('searching for...' + xpath_lic);
    var found = this.evaluate(function() {
        return __utils__.getElementByXPath(xpath_lic);
    });
    if (found) {
        this.echo('Lic found');
    }
    else {
        this.echo('Lic not found');
    }
});
```

The above code is always print out "Lic not found"!
But when I change the return line with:

```js
return __utils__.getElementByXPath('//*[contains(text(), "FAT32")]');
```

This will give me "Lic found" which is correct!

How do I have to use the licid in the `__utils__.getElementByXPath()` to make the line more general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) is the sandboxed page context (derived from [PhantomJS' `page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html)). It has no access to variables defined outside of it. You have to explicitly pass them in:

```js
var xpath_lic = '//*[contains(text(), "' + casper.cli.get("licid") + '")]';
var found = this.evaluate(function(xp) {
    return !!__utils__.getElementByXPath(xp); // convert to boolean with `!!`
}, xpath_lic);
```

You cannot pass DOM nodes out of the page context, so you need to either get a representation of them like `element.textContent` or completely work in the page context.

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**